# Highcharts Gantt chart dependency connecting paths slow to respond when scrolling

Tags: highcharts

I'm experiencing a strange performance issue with the Gantt chart and it appears to be happening with the official demo as well.

I started with this demo code: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt/subtasks

The only change I made was that I added vertical scrolling (yAxis) with a max of 6. The issue is that the dependency lines don't scroll smoothly with their corresponding bars. They lag behind and struggle to catch up to the bars to which they are connected.

[image]

Note in this picture that the dependency arrows are not stationary in the wrong position. They simply lag behind during vertical scroll and slowly move to reattach to their corresponding bars. I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox -- same result. What's even more strange is this same code doesn't exhibit this behavior on JSFiddle or CodePen.

Here is a link to my version: http://tanoro.com/files/ganttchart2.html

I want my users to be able to scroll the chart in cases where there is a bigger data set, but the issue with the lines lagging behind is just visually off-putting. Is there a performance fix for this?

There is also a side issue that scrolling doesn't work via the mouse wheel or PgDown key. A fix for that would also be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `yAxis.scrollbar` you can use `chart.scrollablePlotArea` which works much better in this case. Then there is no problem with dependency lines.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pLr6q0sf/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/chart.scrollablePlotArea.opacity

Additionally, you can report this behavior to the library repository on GitHub as a bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose